# JQuery проблема с клик событиями

Tags: jquery, javascript

есть такой  код  для джейквери

```
("button.less").click(
    function()
    {
        var id1 =$(this).attr("name");

        $(id1).fadeOut('fast',function()
            {
                alert("less");
            }
        )
    })

$("button.more").click(
    function()
    {
        var id =$(this).attr("name");
       var bt= "button.more";

        $(".post").fadeOut('fast',function()
        {
            $(bt).removeClass("more").addClass("less");
            $(".less").empty();

            $(".less").text("LESS");

            $(id).css("max-width","none").fadeIn();

        }
        );
    }
```

Код кнопки

```
  <button  type="button" class="more" name="#p3" >MORE</button>
```

Проблема в том что все время срабатывает только 2ое событие. Даже когда у кнопки убирается класс "more". Что нужно исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что происходит при вызове `$("button.more").click(...)`:

1. Найти все элементы с соответствующим селектором.
2. Добавить им обработчик клика.

как видите никто не смотрит когда и на что поменяется класс в процессе работы программы. обработчик уже висит и для кнопки `button.less` (когда она вдруг появится) никто вешать не будет, потому что на момент навешивания обработчика элементов, соответствующих селектору `button.less`, не существовало.

Чтобы работало так, как вы хотите, вам надо использовать [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on("click","button.less",function () {
    var id1 = $(this).attr("name");
    $(id1).fadeOut('fast', function () {
        alert("less");
    });
});

$(document).on("click","button.more",function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("name");
    var bt = "button.more";

    $(".post").fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $(bt).removeClass("more").addClass("less");
        $(".less").empty();
        $(".less").text("LESS");
        $(id).css("max-width", "none").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: По-моему лучше прямо в обработчике класс проверять, чем на весь документ вешать.